# Application for viewing log files

Tags: logging

Manually listing log files in an editor is so boring. Are there any applications for viewing/filtering log files exists?

Please, suggest something really cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ELK stack](https://www.elastic.co/webinars/introduction-elk-stack). We are using this. Its pretty good.
Its just a mixture of logstash, elasticsearch and kibana. All are open source.